# How do I simplify this update function array code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have update array function I want to simplify this code if possible.
This update function is about updating and comparing the value of array.
The data will be compared inside the `fruit_temp`
example data of `fruit_temp` `fruit_db_id` is and existing id inside the database.

```
fruit_temp = [{
    fruit_db_id: 71,
    fuit_id    : 1,
    name       : 'papaya'
  }, {
    fruit_db_id: 73,
    fuit_id    : 3,
    name       : 'apple'
  }];
```

I will get and read the fruit_temp value and when its to perform update function it will compare the existing and the new value that will inserted. This is the solution for this update function. I just want to know if this code can be simplify or not.

```
const updateFruit = () =>
 { 
        finalFruit_temp     = [];
        let fruit            = $('#fruit').val(); //getting fruit value

        fruit = fruit.map(Number); //convert string value to integer

        fruit.map((el) =>{
            let fruitData = fruit_temp.filter((e) => e.id === el)[0]; //return index if compare true

            finalFruit_temp.push({
                "fruit_db_id"  :(fruitData == undefined) ? null : fruitData.fruit_db_id,
                "fruit_id"     :(fruitData == undefined) ? el : fruitData.id,
                "status"       :true
            });

        });

        fruit_temp.map((el) =>{
            let checkedFruit= fruit.includes(el.id);

            if(checkedFruit == false)
            {
                finalFruit_temp.push({

                "fruit_db_id"  :el.db_id,
                "fruit_id"     :el.id,
                "status"       :false

                });
            }
        

        });
    }
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, nothing is here to simplify. If you want reducing, then remove comments and linebreaks on empty lines . Well, this question isn't neccessary here. Again, remove the breaks for only 1 parameter in an arrow function `(el) =>{` to `e => {`

Comment: An `Array.prototype.map()` that doesn't return anything should probably be either an `Array.prototype.forEach()` or (my preference) a simple `for (const el of ...) { ... }` loop.

Comment: I just wonder why can you use el.Id or e.id if there is no id in the object? I only see a fruit_id

Answer (score 0):

This code seems well simplified, but I see a few things you could do to make it even shorter. Defining variables in a one liner and changing the last condition statement.

```
const updateFruit = () => { 
  
  finalFruit_temp = [];
  let fruitData, fruit = $('#fruit').val().map(Number); 

  fruit.map((el) => {
    fruitData = fruit_temp.filter((e) => e.id === el)[0]; 
    finalFruit_temp.push({
        "fruit_db_id"  :(fruitData == undefined) ? null : fruitData.fruit_db_id,
        "fruit_id"     :(fruitData == undefined) ? el : fruitData.id,
        "status"       :true
    });
  });

  fruit_temp.map((el) => {
      if(!fruit.includes(el.id)){
          finalFruit_temp.push({
            "fruit_db_id"  :el.db_id,
            "fruit_id"     :el.id,
            "status"       :false
          });
      }
  });
}
```